# How to add date and time to a geotiff to enable time dimension in geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff, time

I have a collection of geotiff files, each one corresponding to a date YYYYMMDD.

How can I had the information date to those geotiff, so that geoserver allows the enabling the "Time" dimension for this layer?

Comment: Time is not added into GeoTIFF files but into the index file that is used for making the image mosaic. Read this document first http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/image_mosaic_plugin/imagemosaic.html#tutorial-imagemosaic-extension

Comment: the easiest way is to encode the date/time in the file name and use the indexer

Comment: You mean the image mosaic indexer (http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/multidim/en/imagemosaic/mosaic_indexer.html) ? Would you have some examples, or tutorials to share?

Answer (score 3):

Geoserver offers the Image Mosaic plugins, which allows either mosaicing or making time series. 
This pages shows how to build such a time series:
http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html

Basically, it consists in having all the tif in a single repository, and creating at least two configuration files: timeregex.properties defining the rules for extracting the date from the filename, and indexer.properties indicating to geoserver how to create the index table. The third file is needed only to create entries in PostGIS (else geoserver will create a shapefile).

Creating a new datastore is quite straightforward. A time parameter can then be passed to the WMS to select a specific image.